# Need to preserve line breaks from user-entered textarea to email body

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have the following Javascript to copy the user's textarea input in this iPhone app (built with HTML/CSS/Javascript for PhoneGap), open the email client, and paste it into the body. This script does all that. Unfortunately, the textarea's line breaks are not preserved, making it a horrible reading experience. How do I preserve the textarea's line breaks? I read through 12 questions with a similar title on Stackoverflow without seeing the same case as mine.

Form code (with Jquery):

```
<div data-role="content"><form name="form2" action="mailto:" type="text/html" onSubmit="send_setupSummaries(form2); return false;">
```

Javascript:

```
var setupSummaries = document.getElementById('setupSummaries');

function send_setupSummaries(form2) {
"use strict";
var eml="";
var subj= "?subject=from SC10 Setup App";
var bod = "&body="+form2.setupSummaries.value;
location.href="mailto:"+eml+subj+bod;
}
```

Textarea:

```
<li><textarea name="setupSummaries" cols="20" rows="7"></textarea>
```

This is what I've tried so far and none have worked. The commented lines are alternate ways that have failed:

```
var setupSummaries = document.getElementById('setupSummaries');

var str = document.getElementById('setupSummaries');
//setupSummaries = str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '<br>');
//setupSummaries = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
//setupSummaries = str.replace(\n\r/g, '<br>'); // Mac uses \r
//setupSummaries = str.replace(/\r/g, '<br>');
//setupSummaries = str.replace(/\r/g, "</p><p>");
var setupSummaries = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"</p><p>");
```

Comment: Try setting the "wrap" attribute to "hard" on the `<textarea>` element. (I think you might also have to set "cols" to be the width in characters that you want the lines to be broken at.)

Comment: If it's an HTML email, you need to replace linebreaks with `<br/>` tags. If it's text email, it should work as-is.

Comment: @pointy Wrap attribute did not work in this case.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am researching Replace() now.

Comment: Hmmph.  Well, a lot depends on how the mail client responds to the "mailto:" URL too I guess, and of course different mail clients may respond differently.

Comment: This is the iPhone email client. I don't know the details of its inner workings in this regard.

Comment: I added several attempts I've tried to the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're putting together a `mailto:` URI, so URI-encode the message body:

```
var bod = "&body="+encodeURIComponent(form2.setupSummaries.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks may be there in the form of a `'\n'` or `'\n\r'` characters. You may want to split your text on those character and encapsulate substrings in `<p>` tags, or replace `'\n'` with `'<\br>'` tags